# Change Firefox Picture-in-Picture background color in fullscreen

Tags: firefox, video

Firefox has a Picture-in-Picture mode (PiP) for video playback. Once you double-click the hovering PiP video, it will maximize to fullscreen: with a white background color by default.

How to set a custom background for PiP fullscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (Firefox 70.0b4) there're no own settings specifically for PiP. Instead, PiP uses this setting for background color:

In `about:browser` the setting `browser.display.background_color` defaults to `#FFFFFF` - white. Changing this setting immediately has effect on the background color used by PiP. For full black, enter `#000000`.

There's one drawback to this: it sets the default background color for any website, if you browse old HTML pages that don't set it (usual white background), you will change the color there too.